# Mixing Blazor and css styles via code behind how to add a style dynamically onclick

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

Basically am building a quiz engine to learn and understand .net 8 with the new features of blazor.

I am wanting to when my user guesses a correct answer to make the button go green now what I have works but as you see it activates on the style property I still want the slection event to fire as I have some logic there.

Bare in mind am using the new blazor web app template in dotnet 8.

But I want to be able to apply the style to the div via the on click method

```
@using BlazorQuiz.Components
@using BlazorQuiz.Pages
@inherits OptionCardBase
<div @onclick="() => OptionSelected(option)"
         style="@GetOptionStyle(option)">
        @option
    </div>
```

In My Base Class for my component I have

```
 public class OptionCardBase : ComponentBase
 {
     [Parameter]
     public string Option { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     [Parameter]
     public EventCallback<string> OnOptionSelected { get; set; }
     [Parameter]
     public string Answer { get; set; } = string.Empty;

     private string selectedOption;
     private string selectedOptionStyle = "";

     public string GetOptionStyle(string option)
     {
         
         bool isCorrect = option == Answer;
         // Update the selected option
         if (isCorrect)
         {
             selectedOptionStyle = "background-color:  #00FF00;"; // Apply style for correct option
         }
         else
         {
             selectedOptionStyle = "background-color: #FFFFFF;"; // Apply style for incorrect option
         }

      
         // Return the appropriate style based on the selected option or any other condition
         return selectedOptionStyle;
     }
     protected async void SelectOption()
     {
         await OnOptionSelected.InvokeAsync(Option);
     }
```

What I need to no is how do i get the style returned to the div without having it in the style tag? Is that even possible just via blazor? If I just add

```
GetOptionStyle(Option);
```

In Selection options obvs that will not do anything